# What directory does chaquopy code search for the Python packages which are imported in the Python code of the Android app code

Tags: python, nltk, chaquopy

I have imported nltk library in my main method of the Python code of the chaquopy Android app. It is asking me to implement `nltk.download('punkt')` for my processing. So I wanted to know: in what directory does the code look for the packages, so that I can download a copy of them in the desired folder for my code to work right?

**Edit**: I implemented the solution provided by @mhsmith, but nltk.download('punkt') is still giving Lookup Error.
Screenshots are attached:

The first line is the download_dir in which nltk.download('punkt') is downloading data

[image: The first line is the download_dir in which nltk.download('punkt') is downloading data]

This is the error I am getting even after implementing solution by @mhsmith

[image: This is the error I am getting even after implementing solution by @mhsmith]

This is the snippet of my code

[image: This is the snippet of my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chaquopy 4.0.0 and newer**

These versions set the `HOME` environment variable to your app's files directory, and nltk will automatically create an `nltk_data` subdirectory there. So no special action is required.

---

**Chaquopy 3.3.2 and older**

I think the cleanest solution would be to create a separate directory for your downloads, like this:

```
from com.chaquo.python import Python
download_dir = "{}/nltk".format(Python.getPlatform().getApplication().getFilesDir())
if not os.path.exists(download_dir):
    os.mkdir(download_dir)
nltk.download(..., download_dir=download_dir)
```

(The `getPlatform` method requires Chaquopy 3.2.0 or later.)

From the [NLTK documentation](https://www.nltk.org/data.html), it looks like you'll have to set the `NLTK_DATA` [environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) to this directory. This should probably be done *before* you `import nltk`.

Comment: I have inserted the snippets of the code in the folowing answer to the above question. please clarify the issue

Comment: @utkarshverma If your app is based off the "hello" example I guess you're using Chaquopy 3.1.0. Please edit your build.gradle to upgrade to version 3.2.0.

Comment: I have edited the question with the doubts. Additionally I have one more doubt that what does setting environment variable in system do if the app is running on mobile. I mean, if I set the download_dir path in the system as shown in snippet, the error of directory doesnot exist occurs

Comment: The app is giving some new errors as attached in Edit. Any help would be great

Comment: @utkarshverma I've added a link in my answer explaining how to set an environment variable. This should probably be done *before* you `import nltk`.

Comment: But how would adding environment variable in PC help when the app would run on mobile app

Comment: It's not on the PC. Apps have their own environment variables as well, and that link tells you how to set them from Python code.