# Can't start java.exe for stanfordtagger in android via python script and chaquopy

Tags: java, python, android, stanford-nlp, chaquopy

I want to start my python script, which analysis text data with nltk and stanford tagger.
The problem is that i have no permission to start the copied java.exe.

The code for starting the stanfordtagger is :

```py
    #set java path in environment variables
    java_path = fct.lib_dir + "java.exe"
    os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
    #load stanford NER
    sn = StanfordNERTagger(
    fct.lib_dir+"german.distsim.crf.ser.gz", 
    path_to_jar=fct.lib_dir+"stanford-ner.jar")
```

This is the error:

```
    com.chaquo.python.PyException: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/com.pro.useyournotes/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/app/library_files/java.exe'
        at <python>.subprocess._execute_child(subprocess.py:1702)
        at <python>.subprocess.__init__(subprocess.py:854)
        at <python>.nltk.internals.java(internals.py:132)
        at <python>.nltk.tag.stanford.tag_sents(stanford.py:113)
        at <python>.nltk.tag.stanford.tag(stanford.py:91)
        at <python>.uyn_pre_processing.get_tagged_stanford_corpus(uyn_pre_processing.py:185)
        at <python>.uyn_analysis_workflow.analyse_new_data(uyn_analysis_workflow.py:63)
        at <python>.uyn_main.main(uyn_main.py:268)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:285)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrows(chaquopy_java.pyx:257)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(Native Method)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:209)
        at com.pro.useyournotes.MainActivity.getPythonHello(MainActivity.kt:70)
        at com.pro.useyournotes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

How can i solve this problem? Or is there any other option to access the copied java.exe
(from: *"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin\java.exe"* to the direction: *lib_dir = join(dirname(**file**), "library_files/"*)
) windows in the python script?

```
java_path = fct.lib_dir + "java.exe"
```

Comment: *python* process can't access to file you're trying to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you'd need to do much more in order for this approach to work. You'd need to provide a complete JRE, not just the `java` executable, and it would have to be built for Android, not Windows. I'm not aware of any easy way to do this, so I recommend you look at other options, such as:

- Add the JAR to your `app/libs` directory and call it from Java or Kotlim
- Or simply use a different tagger.

Comment: this is really bad, because i'm combing this and another tagger for my optimized result. How is it possible to start the ner tagging analysis with the jar and kotlin?

Comment: If you have the default "libs" line in the `dependencies` section of your build.gradle file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25660223), then it should be enough just to put the JAR in app/libs, and then you'll be able to access its Java classes from your Kotlin code.

Comment: Yes i have the default "libs" line, but i don't know how to access the JAR and how to use ner_tagging method.

Comment: I have no experience using this library, but it looks like there is plenty of documentation [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) and [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html). I assume that your JAR already has the models built into it, in which case you can go directly to step 6 in the FAQ question ["How can I achieve a single jar file deployment of the POS tagger?"](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.html#d).